# Exclude Date property keys from typescript nested keys

Tags: typescript

I've been searching for a typescript method to give me the nested key paths of an object and found this example which almost covers all my needs:

```
type FieldValues = Record<string, any>;

type Primitive =
  | null
  | undefined
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | symbol
  | bigint;

type IsTuple<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = number extends T['length']
  ? false
  : true;
type TupleKey<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof any[]>;
type ArrayKey = number;

type PathImpl<K extends string | number, V> = V extends Primitive
  ? `${K}`
  : `${K}` | `${K}.${Path<V>}`;

type Path<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer V>
  ? IsTuple<T> extends true
  ? {
    [K in TupleKey<T>]-?: PathImpl<K & string, T[K]>;
  }[TupleKey<T>]
  : PathImpl<ArrayKey, V>
  : {
    [K in keyof T]-?: PathImpl<K & string, T[K]>;
  }[keyof T];

type FieldPath<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> = Path<TFieldValues>;

type ArrayPathImpl<K extends string | number, V> = V extends Primitive
  ? never
  : V extends ReadonlyArray<infer U>
  ? U extends Primitive
  ? never
  : `${K}` | `${K}.${ArrayPath<V>}`
  : `${K}.${ArrayPath<V>}`;

type ArrayPath<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer V>
  ? IsTuple<T> extends true
  ? {
    [K in TupleKey<T>]-?: ArrayPathImpl<K & string, T[K]>;
  }[TupleKey<T>]
  : ArrayPathImpl<ArrayKey, V>
  : {
    [K in keyof T]-?: ArrayPathImpl<K & string, T[K]>;
  }[keyof T];

type PathValue<T, P extends Path<T> | ArrayPath<T>> = T extends any
  ? P extends `${infer K}.${infer R}`
  ? K extends keyof T
  ? R extends Path<T[K]>
  ? PathValue<T[K], R>
  : never
  : K extends `${ArrayKey}`
  ? T extends ReadonlyArray<infer V>
  ? PathValue<V, R & Path<V>>
  : never
  : never
  : P extends keyof T
  ? T[P]
  : P extends `${ArrayKey}`
  ? T extends ReadonlyArray<infer V>
  ? V
  : never
  : never
  : never;

type FieldPathValue<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
  TFieldPath extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>,
  > = PathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldPath>;

type FieldPathValues<
  TFieldValues extends FieldValues,
  TPath extends FieldPath<TFieldValues>[] | readonly FieldPath<TFieldValues>[],
  > = {} & {
    [K in keyof TPath]: FieldPathValue<
      TFieldValues,
      TPath[K] & FieldPath<TFieldValues>
    >;
  };

// Example
type Order = {
  customer: string, 
  products: {
    description: string,
    quantity: number
  }[],
  meta: {
    createdAt: Date,
    createdBy: string,
  }
}

type OrderFieldPaths = FieldPath<Order>;
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwGoENEFcIGcoC8UAShAMYD2ATsgDy7BVwB2A5gDRTrMgB8A3AFgAUCNCQoABSYBbOMDgA3aARFQoAHyjMsiRGs1QszZBABmLCMgNaGTNje1YZAIwhVHLihUQRuj3BBXH084VhZgIVFhcWgASVwAFSwwX1pEqAgAD2AIE3xSdGQKZkQQAEEqKnQQWm4+XkInV3dMnLzkfESAbQByXzZgAAtegF0DAH4oM0xcCAMALihGHCjYqGTUiABpCFqM7Nz8kj9i0oqqmrqeXkaiAFEssmxTWgBrPYozDc4PkC+uDxuqMBGJwNBKtUQLsQE0dC0qFEwRJJOhhnEZKlaNs2kdOlA7CxWIZ4W4qJxUHcoKhcR18NI4HIFMpJlAAAYAEgA3tsAL5sxbs7l8tmGTk83kAOm5qOGtEp-KRMXBUjRQ3SVIO7WOhTOZUhVxYZlalNZCU2aUSjUOdOWVBwrK5BnU3RxLA2KV8MI1owAtBMlrKhhisTiAGQExhEzg9bYgqLqXndC07PY+wVBkOIWgG6F7Cm8QVO4TqF1u5hQP4AxJ+gOq9GY7PhyP2DgbV3xgxJqvfGtK9bwJDIIPpQcoDDYPC045jtCYHC4KkjxKzicL0HRda5zON7HT-GEtgk5xkgtNGk244MplKeYlqBTZgQZQee9LC-a-G6kr6y61I2tAAqoW95TIB+70rI8i3qyT4voK4oimKwpSty25qvKvD8ghKHSly6FygqbL9iqBHqlaTRaniBSnD+FxQrQAFUNSIHqFM5qehAGoQXaDqgVAxallArpQO6KbelatZLGRWZ7hGh5trGnb3km4lppJgoybuuYwgWRbOsJ5aVp8vZSVAWmhlA8lRmwMYdhuibdD2GyjCRKJqmuXGJJwkg8cujRaGRGqajx9Ssr5l74uKTFQHyeExcQ2H8TikX4M5iSssQfkYUprEPvWQyeekHacMQeVLHB7iCiln74OKOl7ElbEbDx37nLmjHMMazGmvxQZFagpVWQVmHldoz5VW+43wVNEW1cZ-y9qyPSSOMs08fVf4wk1+VUbabW-gxMW9c1qCCpVr7qBVE2XVA10vm50Czv185cQYK4IOOr34KlsCfXOk64Ow73PWqPGg3KH1Dp5i7A-eS4ea9o7-TDMYQ0MG7Ik9-0vYDtAgyj33g4TgNw+oiRBsTQ7Lqu328MChhULR5x-dTOW04D9OjGTUBUlyvLDYJpYie66VBqMSzo0VBnkxzC480JFNqh2w3o8j0N0wZDlQLySoAPR61AjzoI2d7rAA8jQrREELZBYAwFAyO4SwKZwBhgFQFDIFgZDALgSxC+opi4GQTBgAoJQuzZHAGQAjlg3AKKAFUnpNjncwYTvAOgAcGaHfi5Mg5TAEsAAiaIQArUD5xXyAAEIgFHrY87yIit5uKqW6YVDo-gRBq137gCEAA)

The type "OrderFieldPaths" results in this string union:

```
type OrderFieldPaths = 
"customer" | 
"products" | 
"meta" | 
`products.${number}` | 
`products.${number}.description` | 
`products.${number}.quantity` | 
"meta.createdAt" |
"meta.createdBy" | (the following is what I want to exclude)
"meta.createdAt.toString" | 
"meta.createdAt.toLocaleString" |
"meta.createdAt.toDateString" |
 ... 40 more ... | 
"meta.createdAt.getVarDate"
```

This is basically exactly what i want, except I also want to exclude all the native date functions and properties (just like it does with arrays), so that the OrderFieldPaths becomes just:

```
type OrderFieldPaths = 
"customer" | 
"products" | 
"meta" | 
`products.${number}` | 
`products.${number}.description` | 
`products.${number}.quantity` | 
"meta.createdAt" |
"meta.createdBy" |
```

My only problem is that it will also include all Date properties and methods. Any way to modify the example so that it only includes the date property itself and not the native Date properties / methods?

Comment: Please include your code directly as text in the question for this to be a [mre].  A link to an external IDE is a nice supplement but doesn't suffice.  I would [edit] the question for you to do this, but it's not clear that anyone but you has the copyright to do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the example directly in the question

Comment: So you just want to stop on `Date`, right? If yes [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVl07W) should work?

Comment: @wonderflame Yes, I would like to be able to select the date property itself, but not any of the native Date properties. In your link it still lists all nested date properties.

Comment: Can you inclue test case please? Not sure if I understand

Comment: @wonderflame I've added a better example